# verify « have a coupon form » and redirection

Tags: redirect, woocommerce, coupon

If i understand well, it is possible to add a product and apply coupon via an url:

Website.com/cart/?add-to-cart=ID-PRODUCT&apply_coupon=CODE-COUPON

or directly on chekout page (better Way if the product + coupon = 0$ (free)) :

Website.com/checkout/?add-to-cart=ID-PRODUCT&apply_coupon=CODE-COUPON

(Adresse web is for understanding only = don’t work)

Is it a Way to do that dynamicly ?

1/ the customer add the code coupon on the Field of the Form
2/ if the coupon is not valide, just do nothihng (only message « coupon not valide » appeared)
3/ if coupon code is valide, the product’s coupon and the product in relation with this coupon is add to cart or on chekout page automaticly : the customer only need to validité order (free order)

Have you an Idea ? Can yu help me with this?

---

The form in use for coupon (added to functions.php file of the child theme wordpress) is :

```html
//* usage: [coupon_field] or in Php code echo do_shortcode("[coupon_field]"); *//
add_shortcode( 'coupon_field', 'display_coupon_field' );
function display_coupon_field() {
    if( isset($_GET['coupon']) && isset($_GET['redeem-coupon']) ){
        if( $coupon = esc_attr($_GET['coupon']) ) {
            $applied = WC()->cart->apply_coupon($coupon);
        } else {
            $coupon = false;
        }

        $success = sprintf( __('COUPON CODE "%s" is valid!'), $coupon );
        $error   = __("COUPON CODE is not valid!");

        $message = isset($applied) && $applied ? $success : $error;
    }

    $output  = '<div class="cadre-coupon"><div class="redeem-coupon"><form id="coupon-redeem">
<p><h2 style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #ff00ff;">REDEEM COUPON CODE</span></h2></p>
<input type="text" name="coupon" id="coupon" placeholder="Enter your COUPON CODE HERE..."/>
<input type="submit" class="bouton-coupon" name="redeem-coupon" value="'.__('Redeem COUPON CODE').'" /></p>';
$output .= isset($coupon) ? '<p id="resultat-coupon">'.$message.'</p>' : '';
return $output . '</form></div></div>';
}
```

How after verification of this form, redirect user to the checkout inluded the COUPON ID and the Product ID associated (and appliqued) (so the user just valid the "free checkout" to receive the free product ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: So the question is: how make a redirection after the form (have a coupon?) if the coupon code is good (valid) and redirect user to the checkout with the « int ID coupon code » + the « int ID product associated » ?